# How to list BIOS Major/Minor Release Version using PowerCLI?

Tags: powershell, bios, powercli, esxi

I'm trying to make sure that I have the correct BIOS versions on a series of HP Proliant servers running ESXi. I would like to use PowerCLI to return the BIOS Major Release and BIOS Minor Release information for each host.

So far, when using PowerCLI to query the BIOS information, I only get the basic version information ("P89"), as shown below (I've obviously omitted the real hostname values):

```
PS \> Get-View -ViewType HostSystem -Filter @{'Name' = $servername} | select Name,
>> @{N='BIOSversion';E={$_.Hardware.BiosInfo.BiosVersion}}

Name                        BIOSversion
----                        -----------
$servername                 P89
```

However, if I SSH into that host I can use *'vsish'* to identify the BIOS Major Release and BIOS Minor Release information (i.e. v2.76):

```
root@<servername>: ~# vsish
/> get /hardware/bios/biosInfo
BIOS Information (type 0) {
   BIOS Vendor:HP
   BIOS Version:P89
   BIOS Release Date:10/21/2019
   BIOS Major Release:2
   BIOS Minor Release:76
   Embedded Controller Firmware Major Release:2
   Embedded Controller Firmware Minor Release:73
}
```

Is there a way to use PowerCLI to return the BIOS Major Release and BIOS Minor Release data, without having to SSH into the host directly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `$_.Hardware.BiosInfo.MajorRelease` and `$_.Hardware.BiosInfo.MinorRelease` should have data.

Answer (score 1):

If the information is available in PowerCLI, it will be located at `$_.Hardware.BiosInfo.MajorRelease` and `$_.Hardware.BiosInfo.MinorRelease`. To join the major and minor versions using version syntax, you can do the following with the `-join` operator:

```
Get-View -ViewType HostSystem -Filter @{'Name' = $servername} |
    Select Name,@{N='BIOSversion';E={$_.Hardware.BiosInfo.BiosVersion}},
    @{n='BIOSRelease';e={$_.HardWare.BiosInfo.MajorRelease,$_.Hardware.BiosInfo.MinorRelease -join '.'}}
```

Comment: Thank you, @AdminOfThings!  That's exactly what I was looking for!  Weirdly enough, it only seems to return data for ESXi v6.7, and not for ESXi 6.0, but I can keep digging there..

Thanks again!

Comment: Update from VMware, it looks like ESXi v6.0 didn't include the functionality to allow data be returned from $_.Hardware.BiosInfo.MajorRelease and $_.Hardware.BiosInfo.MinorRelease.